# Finding minimum number in an array with recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

when i dissect the logic of my code, it makes sense to me and looks like it should work. I need to find and return the smallest number in an array using recursion. here is my code

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int start, int last)
{
    int min = numbers[start]; // sets first value in array to minimum

    if(numbers[start]<numbers[last]&& numbers[start]<min)
    {   // if 1st value < last value in array and 1st value smaller than min, set min to first value
        min = numbers[start];

    }
    else if(numbers[start]>numbers[last]&& numbers[last] < min)
    {   // if 1st value > last value and last value < min, set min to last value
        min = numbers[last];
    }
    else
    {   // if 1st and last value are equal returns 1st value
        return numbers[start];
    }
        // recursively calls... or not
    findMin(numbers, start+1, last-1);
    return min;
}
```

inputs used are 33
-55, -44, 12312, 2778, -3, -2, 53211, -1, 44, 0

output getting:

The minimum number is 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Assignment9.countEven(Assignment9.java:72)
    at Assignment9.countEven(Assignment9.java:87)
    at Assignment9.main(Assignment9.java:34)

Expected: -55

i am assuming my recursive call is incorrectly placed. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int start, int last)
{
    if(start == last) return numbers[0];
    return Math.min(numbers[start],findMin(numbers, start+1, last));
}
```

If for some reason you cannot use the Math.min you can always use:

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int start, int last)
{
    if(start == last) return numbers[0];

    int min = findMin(numbers, start+1, last);

    return  (numbers[start] <= min) ? numbers[start] : min;
}
```

The major problems with or solution are:

-> you are not correctly checking the stop case;

-> you are not using the min value calculated in each recursive call;

-> and you are not checking for the cases that you go over the array limits.

Answer (score 0):

First glance, it looks like you are not saving the result from your recursive call, you're just calling it as if it was a void method.

Instead of

```
findMin(numbers, start+1, last-1);
return min;
```

Try:

```
min = findMin(numbers, start+1, last-1);
return min;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple try this:

```
    public static int  findMin(int[] numbers, int start, int last) {
        if(start == last){
            return numbers[start];
        }

        if(numbers[start] <= numbers[last]) {
            last -= 1;
        } else {
            start += 1;
        }

        return findMin(numbers, start, last);
    }
```

OR you can use [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) strategy as suggested by Qriss:

```
    public static int findMin(int[] numbers){
        return findMinHelper(numbers, 0, numbers.length);
    }

    public static int findMinHelper(int[] numbers, int left, int right){
        int min1 = 0, min2 = 0;

        if (left == right - 1){
            return numbers[left];
        } else {
              min1 = findMinHelper(numbers, left, (right + left) / 2);
              min2 = findMinHelper(numbers, (right + left) / 2, right);
        }

        return (min1 < min2) ?  min1 : min2;
    }
```

Comment: nice, but  if (left == right - 1) you still need to return the smaller one of number[left] and numbers[right]

Comment: Does that really matter? If (left == right - 1) both indexes will be pointing to the same element in array, wouldn't it?

Comment: it does matter because they do point to neighboured elements, run with -55, -33, -66  and you'll get -55

Comment: Still I don't see your point. Just to clarify, when `right` is passed in recursion, it's actually `length` of `numbers`, not last index of the array. Besides, I tried to run the code with your input as well and it returns -66

Comment: Ah sorry, i missed that with length, that did the trick, together with the doubke checking of the position in the middle: i.E. you call findMinHelper(numbers,0,1) and findMinHelper(1,2), which corrects the possible wrong answer of findMinHelper(numbers,0,1), when numbers[1] smaller than numbers[0]. But with that you have unnessarily more comparisons.